# C++ Array Assignment in Function Issue

Tags: c++, arrays, function

C++ newbie here and I have run into an issue which I can't figure out.

When I run the code below I get the correct results I expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

void factorize(int *factors, int number)
{

    // declare vars
    int index = 0;

    // find factors of number
    for (int x = 1; x <= number; ++x) {
        // if x is a factor of number, save it to array
        if (number % x == 0) {
            std::cout << "   Index: " << index << ",  F: " << x << "\n";
            index++;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{

    //declare vars
    int triangle = 0;
    int factors[] = {};

    //loop through all numbers
    for (int x = 1; x <= 5; ++x) {

        // calculate triangle value
        std::cout << "initial triangle value: " << triangle << ", ";
        triangle = triangle + x;
        std::cout << "x value: " << x << " , new triangle value: " << triangle << "\n\n";

        // find factors of triangle number
        factorize(factors, triangle);
        std::cout<<"\n";

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Correct results:

```
initial triangle value: 0, x value: 1 , new triangle value: 1

   Index: 0,  F: 1

initial triangle value: 1, x value: 2 , new triangle value: 3

   Index: 0,  F: 1
   Index: 1,  F: 3

initial triangle value: 3, x value: 3 , new triangle value: 6

   Index: 0,  F: 1
   Index: 1,  F: 2
   Index: 2,  F: 3
   Index: 3,  F: 6

initial triangle value: 6, x value: 4 , new triangle value: 10

   Index: 0,  F: 1
   Index: 1,  F: 2
   Index: 2,  F: 5
   Index: 3,  F: 10

initial triangle value: 10, x value: 5 , new triangle value: 15

   Index: 0,  F: 1
   Index: 1,  F: 3
   Index: 2,  F: 5
   Index: 3,  F: 15
```

But when I add the line **factors[index] = x;** to the **factorize** function, I get strange results. For some reason, the value of **triangle** in **main** is modified.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

void factorize(int *factors, int number)
{

    // declare vars
    int index = 0;

    // find factors of number
    for (int x = 1; x <= number; ++x) {
        // if x is a factor of number, save it to array
        if (number % x == 0) {
            std::cout << "   Index: " << index << ",  F: " << x << "\n";
            factors[index] = x;
            index++;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{

    //declare vars
    int triangle = 0;
    int factors[] = {};

    //loop through all numbers
    for (int x = 1; x <= 5; ++x) {

        // calculate triangle value
        std::cout << "initial triangle value: " << triangle << ", ";
        triangle = triangle + x;
        std::cout << "x value: " << x << " , new triangle value: " << triangle << "\n\n";

        // find factors of triangle number
        factorize(factors, triangle);
        std::cout<<"\n";

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Unexpected results (notice how the **triangle** value goes: **0**, **1**, **3**, but then for some reason jumps back to **2**):

```
initial triangle value: 0, x value: 1 , new triangle value: 1

   Index: 0,  F: 1

initial triangle value: 1, x value: 2 , new triangle value: 3

   Index: 0,  F: 1
   Index: 1,  F: 3

initial triangle value: 3, x value: 3 , new triangle value: 6

   Index: 0,  F: 1
   Index: 1,  F: 2
   Index: 2,  F: 3
   Index: 3,  F: 6

initial triangle value: 2, x value: 4 , new triangle value: 6

   Index: 0,  F: 1
   Index: 1,  F: 2
   Index: 2,  F: 3
   Index: 3,  F: 6

initial triangle value: 2, x value: 5 , new triangle value: 7

   Index: 0,  F: 1
   Index: 1,  F: 7
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition

```
int factors[] = {};
```

defines `factors` to be an *empty* array of `int`. Every indexing of it will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*. That the first program works is because you don't actually use `factors`.

If you want a dynamic "array" in C++ you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

If you know the size beforehand, either use that size, or use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: 0 sized arrays are not supported in c++. Many compilers offer it as an extension though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True, but the compiler could allow it as an extension? Without knowing the compiler or what warnings it gives it's impossible to say more specifically.